# Problema ao executar APK Android 9

Tags: android, react-native, apk

gerei um aplicativo com o react-native que está funcionando a função login em todos as versões android desde a 4.1 até 8.1, mas na versão 9 ele não está chamando a rede no momento que é requisitada.

Estou utilizando axios para realizar as requisições. Existe alguma permissão que esteja diferente na versão 9 do Android e por isso ele não funciona?

Comment: A requisição que você está fazendo é para o localhost?

Comment: Não a requisição acontece para o meu servidor e ela está funcionando normalmente nas versões anteriores do Android, mas na 9 ela não funciona. Mas quando estou executando no avd ela roda normalmente, somente após gerar a apk que ela não executa

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente seja a sua biblioteca (axios), no android 9 o uso do http foi totalmente removido, tente adicionar no seu AndroidManifest o atributo android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

...

Dê uma olhada em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: A resposta do Ariel dá o caminho da solução, realmente o http foi retirado das versões 9+ do Android.